# Generating pdf of web page in laravel

Tags: laravel, pdf-generation, dompdf

I want to generate a pdf of a form that a user fills and download it to the users computer.
I tried using the Dompdf package from laravel to do this and everything works fine except the design. The generated pdf does not look exactly like the web page, after doing some searching about this issue, I found out that dompdf does not support a few of the css option.
I was wondering whether there are any other free packages like dompdf that I could use which can have rich styling and convert the web page to pdf with the exact design.

Comment: Did you check your HTML code? http://validator.w3.org/ is a good validator. dompdf is sensitive to wrong HTML.

Comment: Hey there, i will check it now, thank you